# Verify NavigationService popUntil call using mockito

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, get, mockito, stacked

I am writing unit tests for my flutter mobile application and I am trying to test a function that upon execution should pop the back stack until the predicate of the routing function is satisfied. Here is an example of the test code and accompanying navigation code:

```
group('popUntilHomeView - ', () {
  test(
      'when popUntilHomeView is called the application should pop the stack until reaching the home screen',
    () {
  // Arrange
  final navigationService = getAndRegisterNavigationServiceMock();
  final viewModel = CurrentViewModel();
  // Act
  viewModel.popUntilHomeView();
  // Assert
  verify(navigationService.popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == 
  '/home-view')).called(1);
  });
});
```

Here is the code from the NavigationService, which is built on the FilledStacked Architechure.

```
void popUntil(RoutePredicate predicate, {int? id}) {
   G.Get.until(predicate, id: id);
}
```

Here is the result of running the above test:

No matching calls. All calls: MockNavigationService.popUntil(Closure: (Route) => bool, {id: null})
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)

I am using Mockito to mock the navigation service, here is the generated mock function:

```
 @override
 void popUntil(
 _i8.RoutePredicate? predicate, {
 int? id,
 }) =>
   super.noSuchMethod(
     Invocation.method(
       #popUntil,
       [predicate],
       {#id: id},
      ),
      returnValueForMissingStub: null,
    );
```

As you can see the function is getting called it is just not capturing the predicate I defined and instead returning a Closure.

**Question**

Does anyone have any ideas how to verify that the NavigationService popUntil is called with the proper predicate?

**Notes:**

1. I have tried stubbing the function which provided some success but I can't do anything with the return value since the function is declared as void
2. I have tried declaring the predicate as 'any' as an attempt to capture the invocation details but it will not allow since the predicate is not nullable.